# When I connected SQL Server 2019 Management Studio Connection to Integration Services it shows me Error Class Not Registered

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, distributed-availability-groups, basic-availability-groups

I'm installed SQL Server 2019 Enteprisse in the first server and I have other server with SQL Server 2019 Standar Edition ,both server when I tried connect with the Integration Service SQL server 2019  .It shows me the error:
Connecting to the Integration Services service on the computer MyIP failed with the following error: "Class not registered".

[image]

Comment: Did you install the SSIS component when you installed SQL Server 2019?...because that error message makes it sound like you have an old version installed.

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest SSMS version.

Comment: @J.D. Yes , I have  If you refers the  SQL server Integration services 15.0